# Display custom post type category, while in a CPT category, then the posts beneath

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives

I'm trying to list custom post type categories, then the posts beneath them that are contained in that category. This will be on a parent category page.

It should look like:

### To-Go (Parent Category and current page)

Description of parent category or whatever information is loaded into the category description field.

#### Breakfast

Description of this category or whatever information is loaded into the category description field.

Item 1

Item 2

#### Appetizers To Go

Description of this category or whatever information is loaded into the category description field.

Item 1

Item 2

All I've managed to do is show *every* post in that custom post type including posts not in the "to go" category. How can I get this to limit?

My code:

```
$cat_args = array (
        'taxonomy' => 'menus-category',
        'tag_ID' => 54,
        'menus-category' => 'to-go'
);
$categories = get_categories ( $cat_args );

foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    $cat_query = null;
    $args = array (
        'post_type' => 'newmenus',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  => 'menus-category',
                    'terms'     => array( $category->slug ),
                    'field'     => 'slug',
                    'menus-category' => 'to-go'
                )
            )
    );

    $cat_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo "<h3 class='entry-title'>". $category->name ."</h3>"; ?>
            <div id="items">
        <?php 
        while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) {
            $cat_query->the_post();
            ?>
            <div>
                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <header>
        <?php the_title( '<h3 class="entry-title to-go-items" itemprop="name">', '</h3>' ); ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
        <div class="entry-content">
            <span itemprop="description"><?php the_content(); ?></span>
            <div class="to-go-menu-price" itemprop="price" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/price"><?php the_field('price'); ?></div>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <span class="menu-price">
        <?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'nova_price', true ) ); ?>
    </span>

</article>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Your `WP_Query` specifically says to get all published `newmenus` CPTs. You haven't passed it any category restrictions. Add a `'cat'` parameter and set it to `$category->term_id` inside your `$args` array and that will restrict the posts to just the ones in that category.

Comment: If I put in `cat => $category->term_id` it loads nothing. Same with `cat => 54`, `category_name => 'to-go'`, and I've even tried using the taxonomy which usually works for me `'menus-category' => 'to-go'`, but none of these work. I have verified there are published posts.

Comment: Ah, you have a custom `menus-category` taxonomy. A `cat` parameter only pulls from WP Core Categories. Switch it to a `tax_query` instead and that should solve the problem.

Comment: I just implemented that in the args array... but still no luck. I must be doing something wrong here.

Comment: Might want to update your code above with the tax_query if you'd still like help.

Comment: Updated. Still getting all options.